# How does one perform a shallow update on copy with an immutable type in Python? (structural sharing)

Tags: python-3.x, functional-programming, updates, immutability, shallow-copy

I am coming to Python from Scala, where for a given (case) class, I can perform a copy, and in the same step, specify an arbitrary subset of fields is modified. It looks like this in Scala:

```scala
case class Foo(year: Int, album: String)

// here's a Foo
val foo: Foo = Foo(1973, "Larks Tongues In Aspic")

// updated album with (shallow) copy of year in one step
val nooFoo: Foo = foo.copy(album = "Black Beauty: Live at the Fillmore West")
```

*(example kept simple for replicability)*

I have seen many stacko questions about copying immutable data, but not updating it. I would like to have ad-hoc structural sharing in the context of immutable updates.

I have looked at using `namedtuple`, or raising errors in `__setattr__` in order to make an immutable object. Then I guess I could have methods which call `object.__setattr__` which seems to overload the local `__setattr__` method. *But, then does it mean I need to implement a method for every combination of updates I might perform?* That means I need to define up to n! update functions for n fields (in theory). In the case of a class with 2 fields, that might look like this:

```py
import copy

class Foo:
  self.year = None
  self.album = None

  def __init__(self, year, album):
    object.__setattr__(self, "year", year)
    object.__setattr__(self, "album", album)

  def __setattr__(self):
    raise TypeError("i pity the Foo")

  def update_a(self, new_year):
    noo_foo = copy.copy(self)
    object.__setattr__(noo_foo, "year", new_year)
    return noo_foo

  def update_b(self, new_album):
    noo_foo = copy.copy(self)
    object.__setattr__(noo_foo, "album", new_album)
    return noo_foo
```

What is the Pythonic way to perform immutable object updates (a copy with a field modification) without getting trapped into writing tons of class boilerplate? Or, is there something simple I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) supports this behavior with [the `._replace` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._replace) (despite the leading underscore, this is a public method, it's just prefixed with an underscore to avoid colliding with user-defined fields), and it's actually immutable (overwriting `__setattr__` isn't truly immutable).

```
from collections import namedtuple

Foo = namedtuple('Foo', 'year album')

foo1 = Foo(1996, 'Album1')
foo2 = foo1._replace(year=1997)
```

If you don't need compatibility with older versions of Python, and want an easy way to add additional behaviors to the class, [the newer `typing.NamedTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple) is a more flexible way to make named tuples.